# Vector/Array problems, cannot assign index to variable/cannot use variable as the array size(indexes) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Okay so I am trying to convert integers to binary through this convert function, but I am having some trouble with the array/vector use in it. I previously had this working using an array, but I started getting errors on it. I put the array (commented out) I originally used below the vector I am using now. I switched to a vector because it seemed like, from the research I've done, it would be better.

I am getting an error on `tempArray[i] = remainder;` in the for loop.

The error says:

> Error  2   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I read something about overloading, but do not really know what that is.

When I did an array I was getting these three errors on digits `int tempArray[digits];` which I put as the index (For the array just comment out the vector and use the array already commented out):

> Error  1   error C2057: expected constant expression
>
> Error  2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
>
> Error  3   error C2133: 'tempArray' : unknown size

Lastly, I just switched from using Sublime Text 3 and Cygwin as my compiler to using Visual Studios so I do not know if that may have something to do with it.

```
char* convert(int palindrome)
{
    int remainder, digits = 0, dividend = palindrome;

    while (dividend != 0)
    {
    dividend = dividend / 2;
    digits++;   //5 digits, Johns Computer
    }

    std::cout << "Digits: " << digits;

    std::vector<int>* tempArray = new std::vector<int>[digits]; // vector
    //int tempArray[digits]; using an array

    dividend = palindrome;

    for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    remainder = dividend % 2;
    tempArray[i] = remainder;
    dividend = dividend / 2;
    // cout << array[i];
    }

    // cout << setw(3) << palindrome << " in binary is" << setw(3);

    for (int j = 0; j < digits; j++)
    {
        //  cout << array[j];
    }

    if (palindrome == 0)
    cout << 0;
    cout << endl;

    //int *pDriveArray = array[digits];
    //return readDrives(array, digits);

    return 0;

}


int main() {

    char *currDrives = convert(GetLogicalDrives());

    cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

Edit: Fixed the issue with help below. At the end of the convert function, I have `return readDrives(tempArray, digits);` and I am getting an error on tempArray. Whats the proper way to return a vector?

Comment: `tempArray` is (for no apparent reason) a pointer to a vector. `tempArray[n]` is a vector. You can't assign an int to it. Don't use pointers unless you really need to.

Comment: What is the word "palindrome" doing in your conversion function? Are you picking names at random or do you really intend only to accept palindromic numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>* tempArray = new std::vector<int>[digits];
```

Is creating an array of vectors of 0 size.  This is not what you want to do.  Change it to

```
std::vector<int> tempArray(digits);
```

This will create a vector called `tempArray` that has `digits` number of elements.

Comment: Great that was very helpful. Kinda new to vectors so. If could also be so kind, at the end of the convert function, I have `return readDrives(tempArray, digits);` and I am getting an error on tempArray. Whats the proper way to return a vector?

Comment: If you want to return the vector then you need to change your function signature to `std::vector<int> convert(int palindrome)` and then you would just use `return tempArray;`

Answer (score -1):

Your vector errors have been explained above, but not the Array solution. The error your are getting for your array allocation is that variable length arrays are not legal in C++. Your array call `int tempArray[digits];` expects to be given a constant value to allocate at compile time. Since you're using a variable at compile time it has no idea what to allocate.

Instead you should allocate a pointer and dynamically allocate the array when the function is called, like this:

```
//Declare pointer for your array.
int* tempArray = NULL;
...
//Allocate your array once digits is computed
tempArray = new int[digits];
... //do your work
//clean up the allocated memory
delete [] tempArray;
tempArray = NULL;
```

Ideally you should also be checking for the case where digits is 0 and returning an error there instead of trying to allocate an array with 0 elements.

Comment: Why?  You should use a `std::vector`.

Comment: This answers his question about why he was getting errors in his array implementation. A vector is probably better practice in general though.

Comment: He has his array implementation commented out but specifically mentions it is there in the question and how to use it. He also mentioned the errors caused both by this older array implementation in addition to his current vector implementation, and did not understand why that as well was failing. You answer explained how to fix the vector implementation he's using now, but did not mention why his initial Array implementation failed and I thought that might also be good to explain.

Comment: Sorry didn't see he had the VLA commented out.